# IndexOutOfRangeException when creating an Extension Codeunit for a Page Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-services, dynamics-nav

I'm trying to expose a **Function** in a **Codeunit** through a **Page Web Service** in Dynamics NAV (2009 R2). I followed the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd338962.aspx) and the steps in [a blog post](http://dynamicsuser.net/blogs/waldo/archive/2010/05/14/nav-2009-web-services-extending-a-page-web-service.aspx), but I'm getting the following error when connecting to the Web Service:

> **System.IndexOutOfRangeException**: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I've created a **Page Web Service** and a **Codeunit Web Service**, both using the same name, with only the Page Web Service published:

[image: Web Services]

My **Codeunit** contains only 1 Function for the moment and looks like this:

[image: Codeunit]

When I **publish** the Codeunit Web Service as well, I can use it, but the Page Web Service still shows the error.

When I **rename** the Codeunit Web Service, the Page Web Service works again as before, without the Codeunit's Functions, of course.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function in your codeunit have wrong signature. Moreover in the blog it is `Run` function that is used (not user function). Don't know if it's matters.

> Next phase: post the selected invoice. I don't have a method in my web service to post my invoice, so this is where we are going to extend the web service with this possibility. Very simple! I just created a codeunit with a function. In this function, the signature is important: the first parameter should be the same record variable of the page you published (in our case, "Sales Header"). This is my (only) function of my codeunit:
>
> PostInvoice(precSalesinvoice : Record "Sales Header")
> CODEUNIT.RUN(CODEUNIT::"Sales-Post", precSalesinvoice);

Comment: The evidence was there all along... "The first parameter should be the same record variable of the page you published." There's no explanation as to why this is, though. Meanwhile, I found another [blog post](http://www.archerpoint.com/blog/Posts/dynamics-nav-web-service-error-%E2%80%9Cindex-was-outside-bounds-array%E2%80%9D) dealing with the issue.

Comment: There is no mentioning about it in official documentation, but there is an explanation. If you want to call function you will have to know for wich record this function is invoked. You have tried to put PK field in parameter but different tables will have different PK's. And if you alter table's PK (adding field for example) you will not want to modify each and every function that relate to the record.